# Do European PhD programs offer the opportunity to take on teaching assistantship duties?

Tags: phd, europe, teaching-assistant

I know that, in North America, the opportunity is given (and often mandated) to take on teaching assistantships while in a PhD program.

I knew that, often, European PhD programs pay you to do RA from day one. But, in European PhD contracts/programs, are there countries, or universities even, that set conditions under which you have to TA? Or can you even TA in the first place?

Comment: In Finland, everyone is involved in research and everyone is involved in teaching, regardless of the job title — it is just a matter of how much time is allocated for each of these. For a PhD student, typically you would be expected to teach approx. 10 % of your working hours, and the remaining 90 % is hopefully research (which includes all work that is related to your PhD studies, e.g., taking courses).

Comment: There are dozens of countries in Europe, all with different systems...

Comment: I acknowledge that there would be as many answers as there are systems...

Comment: It is strange that there is no mention of the field of study.  I would think that someone who wants a Ph.D. in film criticism would have to pay his own way, while someone who wants a Ph.D. in mathematics would almost always be a TA  and someone who wants a Ph.D. in biochemistry would  almost always be an RA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But, in European PhD contracts/programs, are there countries, or universities even, that set conditions under which you have to TA? Or can you even TA in the first place?

The European universities I am well aware of generally don't distinguish that strongly between TAs and RAs. In reality, in my current university in Switzerland, the "formal" job title of each employed PhD student (which is to say, practically all of them) is German for "Teaching And Research Assistant". Everybody is expected to teach a little, and (clearly) everybody needs to conduct research, so this job title seems appropriate.

What courses each student is responsible for, and what they are expected to do, is typically assigned by the professor / lab head (sometimes after extensive negotiations / arguments within the group leading up to the start of the semester).

Typically, PhD students are expected to only "assist" in the running of a course done primarily by a designated lecturer ("Dozent") or professor. However, in practice, often a large part of the actual work is done by TAs. in my old university, it was also possible to essentially become a lecturer already during your PhD, and from then on do courses officially on your own, without involvement of a professor.

It is not possible to "take on" additional TA jobs to improve one's monetary situation (but then again, standard salary is already around 60.000 Swiss francs for a first-year student - other universities outside of Switzerland pay less, but still substantially more than the stipends that are common in other places of the world).

Comment: The salary is 60k Swiss francs in part due to the high cost of living in Switzerland; what matters more in international comparisons for budgeting purposes is purchasing-power parity.

Answer (score 2):

In France, the possibility to teach during a PhD is pretty much ruled by the nature of your contract (and not the nature of your funding).

For a regular *contrat doctoral*, you are not allowed to teach unless you sign an additional clause. This clause stipulates that you are now authorized to dedicate some time (with a maximum of 64 hours* a year) to teaching. Now if your goal is to pursue an academic career, you should also know that by the end of your PhD, you need to pass a *qualification*: your profile is examined by the *Conseil National des Universités*. I guess there is no need to say that without teaching experience, your chances at passing the qualification are lower.

Note: In France universities, one hour doesn't weight the same depending on the nature of the class:

- 1h of lecturing = 4/3 hour
- 1h of tutoring = 1h
- 1h of practical work = 2/3 hour

Now when I say 64 hours a year, it's 64 hours of tutoring.

Comment: It's not completely correct to say that you need to pass the qualification by the end of your PhD: the qualification is a requirement before applying to positions as Maitre de Conferences, but it can be done at any time.

Answer (score 2):

In Austria, the Netherlands and Germany at least some amount of teaching is quite often expected from a PhD student, as in the USA it may be required for the stipend.  In the UK, this varies by departments and universities, and is normally capped e.g. at 10 hours a week, since your PhD (if funded) is meant to be a full time job.

Answer (score 2):

In Austria, there are many third-party funded PhD students (by the FWF, probably the largest organization for funding in Austria) who are only funded for doing research. Indeed, it is possible for them to teach classes - they get payed extra per class then (as it should be).

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, in Physics in the UK, teaching wasn't an essential part of your PhD, but you could be employed by the department to work as a Teaching Assistant in the labs.

I did this for two semesters while working on my PhD, helping students set up and run experiments. Others in the department did similarly in the computing labs. The pay was generally considered to be quite good, at around £13 per hour, with lab sessions of three hours taking place once or twice a week.

Answer (score 1):

## UK perspective

In UK institutions, teaching is not considered part of the PhD qualification itself, so it is possible to do a PhD without ever teaching.

However, if you intend to pursue an academic career, it is highly advisable to do some teaching, since teaching experience is very important for a lot of academic jobs. Opportunities to do so vary considerably by institution and even by department; some PhD students do teaching at a different institution. In respect of funded PhD students, there may be restrictions (for example, a maximum of 6 hours per week for AHRC-funded students) or even obligations (typically, this would apply in the case of students funded **by** the university itself) as to the number of hours one can teach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you refer to Turkey when you say "European." but I will explain anyway. I know it is different than North America; it may be similar to European programs.

In Turkey, doing Ph.D. is your education; it is not working. So, you can be an instructor if you have done your masters and have working experience in the field. **Instructors not obligated to do Ph.D.** but, most of them do. There are two types of instructors present:

1. Units directly related to rectorship like Turkish Education, Ataturk’s principles and History of Turkish Revolution or theoretical & applied research centers, and other central organizational units.
2. Instructors who run courses as himself/herself and an employee of the department as a subsidiary of the faculty deanship.

Or you can be a research assistant as I am and you run the laboratory parts of the courses with a faculty member or lecturer (mostly lecturers run their laboratory exercises). You help reading homework and quizzes, cannot run courses your own until you finish your Ph.D. **You are obligated to do masters or Ph.D. while you employed** and you expelled after 1 year when your Ph.D. finished. You have a constant wage no matter what are you doing in that semester or holiday. You assist some administrative work in the department and contribute research. You do most of the work with your advisor who responsible of you other than department chair. You have rights as a government employee with retirement, medical insurance, and annual leave in both types of employment.